# Reading INI files using Nini / .NET

Tags: .net

I'm using "Nini" to read INI files. It works well but I've just found a problem that could be a bug. Do you know it?

The situation is when I read a string (using 'get' or 'getstring' functions) which contains = or " signs Nini stop reading the rest of the line and ignore it. It seems that it stops reading after some characters, but I couldn't find a document that describes it or what chars are ignored.

Let me know if you know about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can change this behavior by specifying, that you are reading a "windows style" ini file.
When creating the IConfigSource, first create an IniDocument and specify the ini file

`IniDocument doc = new IniDocument(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, IniFileType.WindowsStyle);
IConfigSource source = new IniConfigSource(doc);`